# How to group by data by 7am of today to next day 7am for a month or a particular time period of the day in a mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I'm grouping data for a month and in that I want data to be grouped by 7am of today to next day 7am to be considered as a day of 24hrs and same for the all the days of a particular month, in a mongodb query.

I need the mongodb query help in mongodb query

Comment: Sure, this can absolutely be done. But not without more information. What have you tried? What do your documents look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: {
            $dateSubtract: {
              startDate: "$timestamp",
              unit: "hour",
              amount: 7
            }
          },
          unit: "day",
          timezone: "Europe/Zurich"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But as stated in the comment, without further details and sample data, it is difficult to give a decent answer.